# Query for a specific item in collection of javascript object literals

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing a few hundred object literals.  Is there a way to query or match a specific one without having to loop through the entire array.

So for example, given:

```
var collection = [ { "id" : "A11", "text": "the text for A11", "data" : "12345" },
                   { "id" : "B14", "text": "the text for B14", "data" : "16542" },
                   { "id" : "C97", "text": "the text for C97", "data" : "54321" } ]
```

Is there a way to retrieve the item with "id" == "B14" without looping through the entire collection?

Comment: If you can guarantee your array is sorted by the key you're looking for, you could do a binary search. @adv12's answer will perform better of you can do that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your container were an object keyed by sub-object id rather than an array, you could do a quick lookup like `collection["B14"]`.  Depending on your situation it might be worth your while to generate such a lookup object from the array and use that from then on.

Example:

```
var collection = {
                   "A11": { "id" : "A11", "text": "the text for A11", "data" : "12345" },
                   "B14": { "id" : "B14", "text": "the text for B14", "data" : "16542" },
                   "C97": { "id" : "C97", "text": "the text for C97", "data" : "54321" }
                 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see.  I'll get the collection created in a different way, this will be mush easier.